# Summarise multiple variables to strings in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to summarize two variables in string. Let's say this is my id

```
 #visit

id  source1    source2 
 1    a          t
 2    c          l
 3    c          z
 1    b          x
```

second dataset:

```
 #transaction
 id    transactions 

 1       1
 3       2
 1       2
```

I'd like to join these data together but convert them to string at the same time:

I can do for one variable ( let's say source 1):

```
library(dplyr) 
%>%  left_join(visit, transaction, by="id") 
%>%  group_by( id)
%>%  summarise( Source = toString(unique(source1)), transactions =    toString(unique(transactions)) )
```

This gives me the following output:

```
id     source       transactions
 1       a,b         1,2 
 2        c           NA
 3        c           2
```

But I wish to summarize for two variables: So my desire output would be something like that:

```
 id     source       transactions
 1       a,t > b,x   1,2 
 2       c,l         NA
 3       c,z         2
```

Comment: `visit %>% left_join(transaction) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(source = paste(toString(unique(source1)), '>', toString(unique(source2))), transaction = toString(unique(transactions)))`?

Comment: Thanks heaps @alistair. It seems true. I'm happy to accept your answer if you post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `paste` the two variables together, using both `sep` and `collapse` to combine:

```
visit %>% left_join(transaction) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(source = paste(unique(source1), unique(source2), sep = ', ', collapse = ' > '), 
              transaction = na_if(toString(unique(na.omit(transactions))), ''))

## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##      id      source transaction
##   <int>       <chr>       <chr>
## 1     1 a, t > b, x        1, 2
## 2     2        c, l        <NA>
## 3     3        c, z           2
```

Beware, though; `paste` and `toString` stupidly coerce `NA`s to strings. You may want to wrap in `na.omit` or use `na_if`.

Comment: Thanks @alistair. It somehow works for me .Do you have any idea how we can have the  combinations of two sources? I mean instead of a,b > t,x can we have a,t > b,x ?

Comment: `visit %>% left_join(transaction) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(source = paste(apply(data.frame(s1 = unique(source1), s2 = unique(source2)), 1, toString), collapse = ' > '), transaction = toString(unique(transactions)))`? You really need to show what the other rows should look like.